# Error When Using sql_server Chef Community Cookbook On Windows

Tags: windows, sql-server-2008, chef-infra

I try to install sql server in Windows using Chef. I use [sql_server](http://community.opscode.com/cookbooks/sql_server) cookbook for that, but I get the following error:

```
Error:Chef::Exceptions::Win32RegNoRecursive: 
registry_key[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQLServer\MSSQL10_50.MSSQL$SQLEXPRESS\MSSQLServer\SuperSocketNetLib\Tcp\IPAll] (sql_server::server line 56) had an error: Chef::Exceptions::Win32RegNoRecursive: Intermediate keys missing but recursive is set to false
```

Comment: Looks like a botched install. Can you try installing again on a fresh box?

Comment: @sethvargo i have installed in fresh box, but still i am getting the error

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug, I've created a pull request on GitHub: https://github.com/opscode-cookbooks/sql_server/pull/15